# CUDA atomicAdd for doubles definition error

Tags: cuda, atomic, nvidia

In previous versions of CUDA, atomicAdd was not implemented for doubles, so it is common to implement this like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626096/why-has-atomicadd-not-been-implemented-for-doubles). With the new CUDA 8 RC, I run into troubles when I try to compile my code which includes such a function. I guess this is due to the fact that with Pascal and Compute Capability 6.0, a native double version of atomicAdd has been added, but somehow that is not properly ignored for previous Compute Capabilities.

The code below used to compile and run fine with previous CUDA versions, but now I get this compilation error:

```
test.cu(3): error: function "atomicAdd(double *, double)" has already been defined
```

But if I remove my implementation, I instead get this error:

```
test.cu(33): error: no instance of overloaded function "atomicAdd" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (double *, double)
```

I should add that I only see this if I compile with `-arch=sm_35` or similar. If I compile with `-arch=sm_60` I get the expected behavior, i.e. only the first error, and successful compilation in the second case.

Edit: Also, it is specific for `atomicAdd` -- if I change the name, it works well.

It really looks like a compiler bug. Can someone else confirm that this is the case?

Example code:

```
__device__ double atomicAdd(double* address, double val)
{
    unsigned long long int* address_as_ull = (unsigned long long int*)address;
    unsigned long long int old = *address_as_ull, assumed;
    do {
        assumed = old;
        old = atomicCAS(address_as_ull, assumed,
                __double_as_longlong(val + __longlong_as_double(assumed)));
    } while (assumed != old);
    return __longlong_as_double(old);
}

__global__ void kernel(double *a)
{
    double b=1.3;
    atomicAdd(a,b);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    double *a;
    cudaMalloc(&a,sizeof(double));

    kernel<<<1,1>>>(a);

    cudaFree(a);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Edit: I got an answer from Nvidia who recognize this problem, and here is what the developers say about it:

> The sm_60 architecture, that is newly supported in CUDA 8.0, has
>   native fp64 atomicAdd function. Because of the limitations of our
>   toolchain and CUDA language, the declaration of this function needs to
>   be present even when the code is not being specifically compiled for
>   sm_60. This causes a problem in your code because you also define a
>   fp64 atomicAdd function.
>
> CUDA builtin functions such as atomicAdd are implementation-defined
>   and can be changed between CUDA releases. Users should not define
>   functions with the same names as any CUDA builtin functions. We would
>   suggest you to rename your atomicAdd function to one that is not the
>   same as any CUDA builtin functions.

Comment: Looks like a bug in CUDA 8 RC to me. It seems the native double atomicAdd() works only with sm_60 but also can be seen with sm_35. Maybe you could solve this by renaming your own version.

Comment: @Eric Yes, renaming resolves it. Post edited to include this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That flavor of atomicAdd is a new method introduced for compute capability 6.0. You may keep your previous implementation of other compute capabilities guarding it using macro definition

```
#if !defined(__CUDA_ARCH__) || __CUDA_ARCH__ >= 600
#else
<... place here your own pre-pascal atomicAdd definition ...>
#endif
```

This macro named architecture identification macro is documented [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#virtual-architecture-identification-macro):

> 5.7.4. Virtual Architecture Identification Macro
>
> The architecture identification macro `__CUDA_ARCH__` is assigned a three-digit value string xy0 (ending in a literal 0) during each nvcc compilation stage 1 that compiles for compute_xy.
>
> This macro can be used in the implementation of GPU functions for determining the virtual architecture for which it is currently being compiled. The host code (the non-GPU code) must not depend on it.

I assume NVIDIA did not place it for previous CC to avoid conflict for users defining it and not moving to Compute Capability >= 6.x. I would not consider it a BUG though, rather a release delivery practice.

**EDIT**: macro guard was incomplete (fixed) - here a complete example.

```
#if !defined(__CUDA_ARCH__) || __CUDA_ARCH__ >= 600
#else
__device__ double atomicAdd(double* a, double b) { return b; }
#endif

__device__ double s_global ;
__global__ void kernel () { atomicAdd (&s_global, 1.0) ; }


int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
        kernel<<<1,1>>> () ;
        return ::cudaDeviceSynchronize () ;
}
```

Compilation with:

```
$> nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_May__4_21:01:56_CDT_2016
Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.26
```

Command lines (both successful):

```
$> nvcc main.cu -arch=sm_60
$> nvcc main.cu -arch=sm_35
```

You may find why it works  with the include file: `sm_60_atomic_functions.h`, where the method is not declared if `__CUDA_ARCH__` is lower than 600.

Comment: I may not keep it using the same name, as that results in the first of the errors above, "function ... has already been defined". How is it not a bug to give a completely unnecessary error, with a very confusing message?

Comment: @kalj, you may keep the same name, but guarded by `__CUDA_ARCH__`. If your declaration is guarded by this macro you should not have the errors listed above. Moreover, this will leave your code with some consistence and clarity. Truely, whether it is a bug or an API support choice is more opinion than technical statement. Choose whichever, but NVIDIA will get the last word on it.

Comment: Perhaps I am not understanding what you mean? If I add `#if ( __CUDA_ARCH__ < 600 )` and `#endif` around the whole function definition in my snippet above, and compile with -arch=sm_35, I still get exactly the same error. And why should it change -- the if case evaluates to true and I get identical code to the first case?

Comment: @kalj, my macro test was indeed incomplete (that is fixed). I provided a complete example wich compiles using CUDA 8.0 RC on linux Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Okay, now this makes sense, and solves the problem. However, I still feel that this is not av very nice behavior from the compiler. The developers do recognize this if not as a bug, but still as an issue. See my edit of the question.

Comment: How do you prevent custom pre-pascal atomicAdd(double, double) to hide the atomicAdd(float, float) CUDA function (device_atomic_function.hpp) on systems >=CC2.X && < CC6.X ?

Comment: @Kriegalex, I would assume the C++ compiler to mitigate between float and double types.

Comment: @FlorentDUGUET it was a thing of namespaces, atomicAdd(double, double) should be outside the namespace, otherwise you have to provide yourself the float version

Comment: I'm confused about the if pragma statement -- if I want to overwrite `atomicAdd(double*, double)` only pre sm_60 and for CUDA <8.0, shouldn't this read `#if defined(__CUDA_ARCH__) && __CUDA_ARCH__ >= 600` with the same following `if`-structure as you said?

Comment: @FlorentDUGUET, why have you edited your answer (replaced `#if condition ... #endif` with `#if !condition #else ... #endif`)? The if-endif version didn't work for me (I guess, it was always true, regardless of architecture), and if-else-endif did, but I wonder if you could tell me why???