# Define atomicAdd function doesn't work in CUDA

Tags: cuda

As CUDA 2.0x doesn't have `atomicAdd()` function for double, then I define the 'atomicAdd()' function as `atomicAddd()` according to this question,

[Why has atomicAdd not been implemented for doubles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626096/why-has-atomicadd-not-been-implemented-for-doubles)

Here is the code for the device function:

```
__device__ double atomicAddd(double* address, double val)
{
    unsigned long long int* address_as_ull =
                             (unsigned long long int*)address;
    unsigned long long int old = *address_as_ull, assumed;
    do {
        assumed = old;
old = atomicCAS(address_as_ull, assumed,
                        __double_as_longlong(val +
                               __longlong_as_double(assumed)));
    } while (assumed != old);
    return __longlong_as_double(old);
}
```

The code is the same except the function name.

Here is part of my kernel:

```
__global__ void test(double *dev_like, double *dev_sum){
    __shared__ double lik;
    // some code to compute lik;
    // copy lik back to global dev_lik;
    dev_like[blockIdx.x] = lik;

    // add lik to dev_sum
    if(threadIdx.x == 0){
        atomicAddd(dev_sum, loglik);
    }

}
```

After I copy the `dev_lik` back to host and add them to `sum`, and I also copy the `dev_sum` back to host `sum1`. My understanding is that the `sum` should be the same of `sum1`, here is my host code to print them.

```
for (int m = 0; m < 100; ++m){
        if(sum[m] == sum1[m]){
            std::cout << "True" << std::endl;
        }
        else{
            std::cout << "False" << "\t" << std::setprecision(20) << sum[m] << "\t" << std::setprecision(20) << sum1[m] << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

and I get the result as following:

```
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
False   -1564.0205173292260952  -1564.0205173292256404
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
False   -1563.4011523293495429  -1563.4011523293493156
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
```

Some results show `False` but the difference between `sum` and `sum1` is very small, have no idea what is the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike mathematical addition, floating point addition is not associative because of the rounding step involved. In situations where atomic operations are necessary, the order of operations is not deterministic. So nondeterministic rounding errors are inevitable.

Comment: Understand it now. Thanks.